# Test whether every element in an array is equal to sum of subsequent elements

Tags: python, recursion

I want to ask how to improve this code. Is it well-written or should anything be changed? Please let me know. And is it a bad thing to use arguments to store some info, such as the argument value here?

Here's the problem:

> Write a recursive function that will receive an array of integers as an argument and as a result will check whether the sum of the array elements after the ith element is equal to the ith element itself. If all elements meet the condition, the function returns 1, otherwise it returns 0.
>
> #### Test cases
>
> ```
> nums([16,8,4,2,1,1]) # 1 first element is 16, we skip it and then  
> # 8+4+2+1+1 = 16
> nums([256,128,64,32,14,7,7]) # 0 first element 256, 128 + 64 + 32 + 14 + 7 + 7 its not 256 so we return 0
> ```

```
def list_of_numbers(nums, value=0, index=1):
    if index == len(nums):
        if value == nums[0]:
            return 1
        else:
            return 0
    else:
        return list_of_numbers(nums, value + nums[index], index + 1)

print(list_of_numbers([16, 8, 4, 2, 1, 1]))  # 1
print(list_of_numbers([256, 128, 64, 32, 14, 7, 7]))  # 0
```

Comment: The identifier `list_of_numbers` is not helpful. And there's no """docstring""". Tell us what it _does_, not what it accepts. We can always choose to express that later with a signature of `def list_of_numbers(nums: list[int], value: int = 0, index:int = 1) -> int:` if we'd like.

Comment: Judging by your problem statement and your example
inputs, my assumption would be that the key test – namely, that `nums[i] ==
sum(nums[i+1:])` – must be true for all values of `i` (other than the last). But
your implementation only verifies that condition for `i = 0`. For example, it
returns `1` for this input: `[3, 1, 1, 1]`. Please clarify.

Comment: [3, 1, 1, 1] this testcase as you give to me it should return one why because we take the first element and then from second element in array we sum to the end for example first element = 3 , and remaining elements are 1 + 1 +1 = 3 and it should return 1 if the remaining elements are not equal to the first element return 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**At least in most situations, if you mean true-false, don't return one-zero**.
The former is more explicit, readable, and communicative. And since `bool` is a
subclass of `int`, the more explicit return values are still usable in numeric
contexts.

**Handle empty sequences**. Your code blows up if given an empty sequence. It
should either return `None` or raise an explicit `ValueError`.

**Naming: functions do things**. Although functions are things (they are
objects), their primary purpose is to do things. As a result, their names
usually involve verbs or verb-like operations. Your function name lacks that:
it has no verb, implies no operation, and tells us nothing about what the
function does (it's actually just an elaboration of the variable `nums`).
Granted, this function is not easy to name (I tried my best below), but even an
imperfect name conveying something about the function's behavior is better than
a bland, noun-oriented name.

**Naming: when feasible, be specific**. The `nums` and `index` names are clear
enough, but what is `value`? Rather than using a generic term like that, select
something more explicit, such as `total`.

**Consider processing the sequence in reverse order**. The function is supposed
to recurse over the sequence to compute a sum and then, at the end, return
whether that sum equals the first number in the sequence. In that context, it
seems a bit more intuitive to go in reverse order, eliminating the need to
check `len(nums)` repeatedly. Just stop when you hit the index of zero.

**Consider using a second function to handle the recursion**. The optional
arguments in your current implementation are not really part of the function's
intended API. A common technique in recursive scenarios like this is
to have two functions: (1) a top-level function for users to call, and (2) a
secondary function to handle the recursion. The first function can
handle any validations (for example, checking for empty sequences) and then
make the appropriate call to bootstrap the recursion. The second function can
be an inner function (as illustrated below) or another top-level function (use
the latter if you ever need to call the recursive function separately, for
example, for testing purposes).

```python
def first_equals_sum_of_rest(nums):

    def check_seq(i, total):
        n = nums[i]
        if i == 0:
            return n == total
        else:
            return check_seq(i - 1, total + n)

    if nums:
        return check_seq(len(nums) - 1, 0)
    else:
        return None
```

**Consider generalizing the recursive behavior**. This programming exercise can
be decomposed into two parts: (1) a simple equality check against the first
number, and (2) computing a sum recursively. Why not make the sum computation a
first-class citizen?

```python
def first_equals_sum_of_rest(nums):
    if nums:
        return nums[0] == recursive_sum(nums, i = 1)
    else:
        return None

def recursive_sum(nums, i = 0, stop = None, total = 0):
    stop = len(nums) if stop is None else stop
    if i == stop:
        return total
    else:
        return recursive_sum(nums, i + 1, stop, total + nums[i])
```

Comment: Thank you a lot this was a question from university which said return 1 if its correct or 0  False